# Параметры открытия pdf. Как защитить файл PDF от копирования

Tags: html, pdf, защита, adobe

Имеется файл pdf, используется просмотрщик Adobe reader, файл открывается внутри "браузера" (1С 8.3), передаю при открытии параметры scrollbar=0, toolbar=0, statusbar=0, navpanes=0 (параметры брал в документе от Adobe https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_open_parameters.pdf). 
Все панельки управления скрыты. Правая кнопка мыши дает возможность распечатать PDF. Нигде не могу найти параметра для запрета печати или отключения контекстного меню.

Кто сталкивался с таким: полная защита документа от печати (варианты подписи и шифрования через саму Adobe Reader не подходят)

Comment: Что прям и ctrl+P нельзя будет нажать?

Comment: По хорошему - да, и это надо перекрыть и кнопку print screen. Но это уже другая тема, возможно нужно будет писать внешнюю компоненту по перехвату нажатия клавиши